# TypeError: data.outputs is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

i have added my detect face Clarifai API  key to the backend so that the autorization code(API) won't show up in the console, and now It stopped detecting all the faces
I'm getting the below error message in the console

```
TypeError: data.outputs is undefined
    calculateFaceLocation App.js:49
    onButtonSubmit App.js:95
    promise callback*./src/App.js/</App/this.onButtonSubmit App.js:72
    React 23
    js index.js:8
    js main.chunk.js:2298
    Webpack 7
```

see backend below

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');




const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1',
        user : 'postgres',
        port: 5432,
        password : 'Moshe6700',
        database : 'smart-brain'
    }
});



const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.send(database.users) })
app.post('/signin',  (req, res) => {signin.handleSignin(req, res, db, bcrypt)})
app.post('/register',  (req, res) => {register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt)})
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {profile.handleProfile(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => {image.handleApiCall(req, res)})





app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('app is running on port 3001')
})
```

image.js in the backend

```
const Clarifai = require('clarifai');

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '489560069986431e89aa152fe709ba94'
});

const handleApiCall = (req, res) => {
    app.models
   .predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, req.body.input)
   .then(data => {
    res.json(data);
   })
   .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to work with API'))
}



const handleImage = (req, res, db) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries', 1)
    .returning('entries')
    .then(entries => {
        res.json(entries[0].entries)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
  }

  module.exports = {
    handleImage:handleImage,
    handleApiCall:handleApiCall
  }
```

frontend code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import './App.css';




const intialState = {
   
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      box: {},
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: ''
      }
    }


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = intialState
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }


  calculateFaceLocation =(data) => {
    console.log(data)
   const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
   const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
   const width = Number(image.width);
   const height = Number(image.height);
   return {
    leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
    topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
    rightCol: width - clarifaiFace.right_col * width,
    bottomRow: height - clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height,
  }
}

displayFaceBox = (box) => {
  console.log(box)
  this.setState({box: box});
}

onInputChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({input: event.target.value})
}

onButtonSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
   fetch('http://localhost:3001/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
      })
   .then(response => response.json())
  .then( response => {
    if (response) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/image', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: this.state.user.id
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(count => {
        this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count}))
      })
      .catch(console.log)
    }
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

}

onRouteChange = (route) => {
  if (route === 'signout') {
    this.setState(intialState)
  } else if (route === 'home') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
  }
  this.setState({route:route});
}




render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     

    <Navigation isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
    { this.state.route === 'home' 
    ? <div>
    <Logo />
    <Rank 
    name={this.state.user.name} 
    entries={this.state.user.entries}/>
    <ImageLinkForm  
    onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
    onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} />
    <FaceRecognition box={this.state.box} imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl}/>
    </div>
    :(
      this.state.route === 'signin'
      ?<Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      :<Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      )


    
  }
  </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your stackstace is quite clear

```
TypeError: data.outputs is undefined
    calculateFaceLocation App.js:49
```

`data.outputs` that is provided to `calculateFaceLocation` function seems to be undefined

From what I see you only call this function in your onButtonSubmit which mean that

```js
   fetch('http://localhost:3001/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
      })
   .then(response => response.json())
  .then( response => {
    // response here is probably not as you expect
    ...
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
  });
```

=> Probably that the `data` that is sent back from your back endpoint is malformatted

Comment: could you show me how to rectify it?
i tried console.log the err in nodejs and this is what i got

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12) {

Comment: code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/53e1df302c079b3db8a0a36033ed2d15/outputs',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"inputs":[{"data":{"image":{"url":"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/close-face-smiling-kid-portrait-260nw-366911432.jpg"}}}]}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Key cf1d1e427e3142e0aa9fd79d42591f22',
      'X-Clarifai-Client': 'js:2.9.1',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4',
      'Content-Length': 136